# HQL and joins - a faster way?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, join, hql

This part of my model is as follows:

```
IQCEntity has many Documents
DocumentCategory has many Documents
```

I am using Hibernate for my ORM.

Now, please consider the following method:

```
/**
 * Get all documents in the supplied IQCEntity which are in the
 * specified DocumentCategory.
 * @param entity the {@link IQCEntity} which holds the Documents
 * @param category the {@link DocumentCategory} which the Documents belong to
 * @return Collection<{@link Document}>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Document> getDocuments(IQCEntity entity, DocumentCategory category) { 
    String q = "from Document d where d.documentCategory.documentCategoryId = :c and d.entity.entityId = :e";
    Query query = session.createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter("c", category.getDocumentCategoryId());
    query.setParameter("e", entity.getEntityId());
    List<Document> documents = (List<Document>)query.list();
    Collections.sort(documents);
    return documents;
}
```

This method works, and brings back the correct results, however it seems to be pretty slow.

If I look at the table structure in the database, the Document table has parent ids (of course it does - else how could it join!), `documentCategory_documentCategoryId` and `entity_entityId`.

We all know that in SQL the correct results can be achieved without any joins at all. How can the same be done in HQL?

I have tried this: (Note the _ instead of .)

```
String q = "from Document d where d.documentCategory_documentCategoryId = :c and d.entity_entityId = :e";
```

but the property is not found.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: documentCategory_documentCategoryId of: com.foo.bar.entities.Document
```

Is there some way to reference the join fields instead of object references?

Comment: Are there indexes on the parent ids?

Comment: Yes there are indexes on both.

Comment: Log the SQL generated by Hibernate and check the query, run a profiler to see what's the hotspot.

Comment: Have you tried to use the identifier property `.id` to avoid the joins?

`String q = "from Document d where d.documentCategory.id = :c and d.entity.id = :e";`

Comment: Thanks wero ! That works nicely. I has no idea that .id was a special property. I expected it to complain that the property was not found, but no, this seems to work well and eliminates the joins.

Comment: @Memran posted this as answer and enhanced a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the joins use the [identifier property](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-identifier-property) `.id`:

```
String q = "from Document d where d.documentCategory.id = :c and d.entity.id = :e";
```

But since you also have the referenced objects you can even write a shorter version, using `entity` and `category` as parameters:

```
String q = "from Document d where d.documentCategory = :c and d.entity = :e";
Query query = session.createQuery(q);
query.setParameter("c", category);
query.setParameter("e", entity);
```

In both versions Hibernate is able to figure out that it actually does not need to join.

Comment: Thank you again! Following on from what you have said, it turns out that my original HQL query is actually NOT performing a join anyway! I feel pretty dumb right now. Hibernate HQL seems to be smarter than me!